# She hoped to have done

Tags: modal-verbs, negation, perfect-constructions

I saw a sentence

***She hoped to have done***

Or a sentence, created with the same structure. I don'tunderstand how it works. Then I saw a full version of it:

***She hoped*** that **she had done**

So, it's like a combination of **Past Simple(hoped)** + **Past Perfect(had done)** but combining them we can't have **Past Perfect**, we have  only **perfect infinitive**.

When I later saw

***She can't have done***

I didn't understand it, too. Since then I've been trying to create a full version of it which would be clear for me. I tried

***It can't be possible*** that **she has done** - I was told it was incorrect

***It can't be true*** that **she has done** - I was told it was incorrect, too

I also have such variants:

***It can't be real*** that **she has done**

***There can't be a possibility*** that **she has done it**

***There can't be a probability*** that **she has done it**

Is there any sentence among those I wrote which can be equaled to **"She can't have done"**?

Comment: *She hoped to have done* isn't really a syntactically valid standalone sentence *(to have done **what**?)*. And that *specific* sequence would require a fairly unusual context to make it a credible utterance within a conversation. But some of your other examples could be perfectly natural in "ordinary" contexts: *"Did Jane go out?", "**She can't have done**. Her coat is still there by the door".*

Comment: Can I say any of my examples (1) It can't be real that she has done 2) There can't be a possibility that she has done 3) There can't be a probability that she has done it) to mean "She can't have done"?

Comment: I think you're confusing the issue here by your non-idiomatic choice of the ***auxiliary*** verb ***to do*** in these examples (as I said before, something like ***She has done*** isn't a meaningful standalone sentence). Try thinking in terms of an ordinary intransitive verb, such as *She can't have **eaten*** (speaker is ***sure*** that she has had nothing to eat, for whatever reason). Completely different to *She can't eat* (Past Tense: *She couldn't eat*), which denies that she is / was ***able*** to eat.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "have done" also carries a special meanign of "to be finished with" or "to stop. See [this Collins entrty](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/have-done) This sense is also used as "have done with", for example "I have done with you. Do not come here again."

So "She hopes to have done." can mean "she hoped to be totally finished." context would be needed to indicate what was being finished or finished with.

Answer (score -1):

> *"She hoped **to do** it."*

It means *she hoped to do it & she did it*.

> *"She hoped **to have done** it."*

Here, the *perfect infinitive* signifies that *she hoped to do it, but she didn't do it.*

> *"She can't have done it"*

= It is not possible that she has done it. (Or, I don't believe that she has done it.)

But,

> *"She couldn't have done it"*

= It was not possible for her to do it.

Comment: 1) Why does "She shoped to do" mean she did it? She only hoped but whether she finally did we don't know. 2) As I understand "She hoped to have done" = "She hoped that she had done". It should mean that she did it.